# Cakephp : search by date ,without range

Tags: cakephp, search, cakephp-2.0

I am new to cakephp. 
How to search by date in cakephp , without range . 
pick a date using date picker and search.
In my index part created records are there .I have one datepicker and search button is there in top of index.ctp.
**In search what should i write**

Creating part finished . In that creating , if i choose a date and view means the details of the particular date should display.

This is my coding

```
 function index()
 {

 $user = $this->Create->find('all');
 $this->set('create', $user);

  }
      function Search()

       { 

       ???


    $user = $this->Create->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('journeydate'=>'journeydate')));
    $this->set('create', $user);
```

}

```
  index.ctp


    <!-- link to add new users page -->

     <script>
      $(function() {
   $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
  });
 </script>
  <?php
   foreach($create as $user ){}
  ?>
   <?php echo $this->form->create("Create",array('action' => 'search',',$user['Create']['id'])); 
     echo $this->form->input('date', 
    array(
       'class'=>'datepicker',
       'type'=>'text'
    ));
  echo $this->form->end("Search"); 
 ?> 

 <table style='padding:5px;'>
 <!-- table heading -->
 <tr style='background-color:#fff;'>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Phone no</th>
    <th>Bus Name</th>
    <th>Ticket no</th>
    <th>Seat No</th>
     <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>Journey Date</th>
    <th>Booking Date</th>
    <th>Amount</th>

    </tr>

 <?php
   foreach($create as $user ){

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['id']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['age']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['gender']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['phoneno']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['busname']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['ticketno']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['seatno']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['from']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['to']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['journeydate']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['bookingdate']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user['Create']['amount']}</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
     }
     ?>

    <tr><td>
     <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Back" ONCLICK="window.location.href='/newcake/creates/create'"></td></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried, and we can help you improve upon it or fix it.  Even if you write pseudo code that's a start, but at the moment, your question basically sounds like "please write my Controller's action for me"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well using the FormHelper like that will create a Form using the POST method.
I have no idea why you would want to suply it with an id. Also, it seems like you expect more then one user to be returned that should start their journey on the selected date... in that case $user['Create']['id'] doesn't make any sense.

change it to this:

```
<?php echo $this->form->create("Create",array('action' => 'search')); ?>
```

In your controller you need to find all the users starting their journey on the selected date:
Since by default the FormHelper uses POST as submit method, you can find the form data in:
$this->request->data['MyModel']['title'];

if your not sure, you can always output the submitted data with

```
pr($this->request->data);
```

Your search function should look like:

```
public function Search(){ 

    $date = $this->request->data['Create']['date'];
    $user = $this->Create->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'journeydate'=> $date,
        ),
    ));
    $this->set('create', $user);
}
```

You should also be more carefull with naming your models, since 'Create' doesn't seems very apropiate in this case.
To get the most out of CakePHP you should live by the conventions.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Comment: @Jereon : It is working fine , after displaying the date , in the same page i Re-freshed  it showing an error ,  Undefined index: Create.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to say what is the problem without the code. Please refer to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration to see how to get more debug info (stacktrace, line numbers and so on). note that you'll always .get php notice warnings for trying to acces unset elements in arrays and so on... Update your original question or open a new one with the extra info